# How to render external display in native resolution?

Tags: macbook-pro, mac, display, hdmi

I've a UHD display connected to MAC via HDMI. But the external display is not rendering in native resolution.

There does not appear to be an option in preferences to set to native resolution of monitor ?

Update :

With SwitchResX preferences I can display in native resolution of 1440x2560, this software is not free. This option should be available on osx ? Option clicking for more resolutions does not display the resolution of my monitor of 1440x2560.

[image]

Comment: Option click the resolution settings, that may help.

Comment: @Spade please see update

Comment: Is your Mac one of the supported ones? https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT206587 Unless it is, I think SwitchResX would be the way to go.

Comment: What resolution is it rendering at currently?

Comment: @Spade That's for different resolutions. 2560x1440@60Hz has been supported over HDMI since rev 1.3 and DisplayPort 1.0, which is why it's so odd that it's not working.